# Remote AJAX data to controller

Tags: ember.js

The code below works as I would expect it to in that I can access the data in the `environments` template via `content.dev.name`.

I'm struggling with populating this data via an AJAX request though.

I have one rest API that returns the structure as in the controller below. It needs to be called once when the app loads.

Here is my working code:

Controller

```
App.EnvironmentsController = Ember.Controller.extend();
App.EnvironmentsController.reopenClass({
  find: function(){
    return {dev: {key: 'dev', name: 'Development'}, prod: {key: 'prod', name: 'Production'}};
    return this.content;
  },
});
App.EnvironmentsView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'environments'
});
```

Route

```
...
router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('environments', App.EnvironmentsController.find());
...
```

Template

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="environments">
    <ul id="env-menu">
      {{#with content}}
        <li>{{dev.name}}</li>
        <li>{{prod.name}}</li>
      {{/with}}
    </ul>
  </script>
```

And here is the controller with AJAX that I cannot get the data through to the template with the same format.

Note: I know response.data.environments itself is returning the same structure as my manually coded object above.

```
App.EnvironmentsController = Ember.Controller.extend();
App.EnvironmentsController.reopenClass({
  environments: {},
  find: function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/environments',
      dataType: 'json',
      context: this,
      success: function(response){
        this.environments = response.data.environments;
      }
    });
    return this.environments;
  },
});
App.EnvironmentsView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'environments'
});
```

Note, I had something similar working when the controller was an array controller, and the data was being returned as an array.  I need to know how to get this working with objects specifically.

Update: More info from questions

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/coder1/csvZX/

I am open to a different pattern.  I'm just trying to wrap my head around fetching an object via and and sending it through the controller.

This is a pretty awesome tutorial ( http://trek.github.com/ ) I started with, and I can make this work with an array controller, just not when I'm working with a single object.

Comment: `App.EnvironmentsController.find()` wont return the result of AJAX request, as `A`jax is `A`syncronous.

Comment: use `set` and `get` , `this.set('environments' , response.data.environments);`

Comment: Yeah, I started out with this tutorial, which worked: http://trek.github.com/ .. And I wondered the same thing, but it worked. referenced: `App.Contributor.find()`

Comment: Also, regarding set & get, I did try that after looking at the API documentation.  I get the error: `Object App.EnvironmentsController has no method 'set'` when I try to use that.

Comment: `return response.data;` is inside success callback of AJAX in the example you linked, you have it outside AJAX. How did you try to use `set`? `this` won't be referencing to the `controller` inside ajax success callback.

Comment: I tried `this.set` and `set` with the same results.  In the tutorial I referenced, you can see the return he has in the success was replaced in his next 2 blocks of code.  He's working with an ArrayController and using Ember API functions to add it. I tried to re-work it into the ObjecctController with no luck last night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tweaked your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cteegarden/csvZX/19/) and it now displays your data correctly.

The key is that the data is handled by a model, not the controller.  I modified your original jsfiddle and broke out the data loading portion into a class that is responsible for creating instances of itself in the `find()` function.  This is the same way Trek's example works.

New model code:

```
App.Environments = Ember.Object.extend({

});
App.Environments.reopenClass({
    find: function() {
        var env = App.Environments.create({});
        console.log("environments find()");
        // simulate an ajax call, hard coding response below
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Fake response
            console.log("fake ajax response");
            console.log(env);
            env.setProperties({
                dev: {
                    key: 'dev',
                    name: 'Development'
                },
                prod: {
                    key: 'prod',
                    name: 'Production'
                }
            });
            console.log(env);
        }, 1000);
        return env;
    }
});
```

The fake ajax call to google didn't work so I switched it out and used a `setTimeout()` call to emulate the delay of an ajax call.

Notice that the `find()` method creates a new `Environments` object, then has the fake-ajax call populate it with data.  `find()` immediately returns the newly created, empty `Environments` object, which is accessed by the controller and the template.  The `setProperties()` method is used to update the properties of this in a way that Ember's bindings system can detect the changes and make sure they propagate into the template.

The only other thing is to update `connectOutlets` to use the new `Environments` model and :

```
router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('environments', App.Environments.find());
```

This line of code calls `find()`, which returns the newly created `Environments` object and passes it to an instance of the `EnvironmentsController` controller, and fills the `{{outlet}}` in the `application` template with the `EnvironmentsView` view.

Make sure to check out the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cteegarden/csvZX/19/) example.

Answer (score 1):

In my observation the possible mistakes you are doing is:

1. `this.environments = response.data.environments;` should use `set`, `addObject` or something Ember way.
2. If you are using variable `environment` instead of `content` use it in template as well.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/csvZX/17/

Comment: I think you've helped me narrow the question down to: How do you asynchronously set the content of a non array controller?  addObject works for an array, but not for an object variable.

Comment: If the content is an array of Objects as in ArrayController, we use `addObject`. For simple cases like yours we use `set` to set value and `get` to get value. If you use set, it will update the variable. If you use `set('environments', {..blahblah..})` it will update `environments` not `content`. `content` is just a variable Ember uses to store content.

Comment: If you can make a fiddle, Someone can look into it.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your help with this.  I'm unfamiliar with fiddle, but I found the site.  I'll make a fiddle with the code. I did try `set('environments', {...})` again but it still says it does not have that method. (called from inside the success response)

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/coder1/csvZX/  I am open to different patterns on achieving this.  Just trying to wrap my head around retrieving external data from a controller and exposing it to a template.